# Does anyone know how to Match two list that are two dimensional list?

Tags: python, list, arraylist, pattern-matching, match

I have two list that are two dimensional list with at least 100 rows. I would like to match A to B or vice versa. But the real problem is instead of typing in row by row from A to match B. Is there a faster way to loop through all the rows from B to match all the rows from B ?

I tried a[0] and a[1] and a[2]. This method will work but i would have to do alot of typing row by row. This will be to much typing especially if its alot of rows?

I have two list that are two dimensional lists. I would like to match any values in A to match any values in B

```
a=[[9, 15, 25],[4, 14, 18, 25],[11, 12, 24, 25],[4, 8, 9, 26]]

b=[[2, 4, 7, 13, 14],[3, 5, 8, 13, 14],[6, 9, 10, 13, 14],[5, 6, 7, 13, 15],[3, 4, 9, 13, 15],[2, 8, 12, 13, 15],[4, 6, 8, 14, 15],[2, 5, 9, 14, 15]]

b0 = [list(filter(lambda x: x in a[0], sublist)) for sublist in b]

b1 = [list(filter(lambda x: x in a[1], sublist)) for sublist in b]

b2 = [list(filter(lambda x: x in a[2], sublist)) for sublist in b]

b3 = [list(filter(lambda x: x in a[3], sublist)) for sublist in b]
```

Is there a faster way to loop through all of the rows? Especially if there are a lot of rows

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Please share the output you're expecting

Comment: 0.[[], [], [9], [15], [9, 15], [15], [15], [9, 15]]  1. [[4, 14], [14], [14], [], [4], [], [4, 14], [14]] 2. [[], [], [], [], [], [12], [], []] 3. [[4], [8], [9], [], [4, 9], [8], [4, 8], [9]]. i would like to found the matching values with the row number from A.

Answer (score 2):

you can just do it like:

```
for item_a in a:
    result = []
    for item_b in b:
        # Compare elements of lists 
        result.append(list(set(item_a) & set(item_b)))
    print(result)
```

output:

```
[[], [], [9], [15], [9, 15], [15], [15], [9, 15]]
[[4, 14], [14], [14], [], [4], [], [4, 14], [14]]
[[], [], [], [], [], [12], [], []]
[[4], [8], [9], [], [9, 4], [8], [8, 4], [9]]
```

EDIT:

```
for idx,item_a in enumerate(a):
    result = []
    for item_b in b:
        result.append(list(set(item_a) & set(item_b)))
    print("{} : {}".format(idx,result))
```

output:

```
0 : [[], [], [9], [15], [9, 15], [15], [15], [9, 15]]
1 : [[4, 14], [14], [14], [], [4], [], [4, 14], [14]]
2 : [[], [], [], [], [], [12], [], []]
3 : [[4], [8], [9], [], [9, 4], [8], [8, 4], [9]]
```

solution with `set.intersection()`:

```
for idx,item_a in enumerate(a):
    result = []
    a = set(item_a)
    for item_b in b:
        result.append(list(a.intersection(item_b)))
    print("{} : {}".format(idx,result))
```

Comment: Didnt notice this comment until now but yes something like this works. is there a way to show the row number from A ?

Comment: check my edit , if i understood correctly it should be the solution @Sofreshnclean

Comment: This solution does list-to-set conversion multiple times for each sublist. For a better performance, the sublists can be converted to sets in a separate loop. Another alternative is to explicitly call `set.intersection` to avoid the need of converting the operand to a set.

Comment: so how do you set.intersection?

Comment: Yes this work  both ways .  One more thing is there a way to define the name of the results?

Comment: what you mean "define the name of the results" can you show an example? @Sofreshnclean

Comment: Something like this Def intersection(df1,df2)

Comment: Is there a function i can do instead of a loop

Comment: I suggest you to open a new question. I do not know about such a function :/

Comment: instead of using print can i use a function?

Comment: print is a function, what you want to achieve with that function?

Comment: The output. Like creating a variable?

Comment: it will only display the last row or last values

Comment: output = [] , output.append("{} : {}".format(idx,result))

Comment: i got an error ----> 1 output = [] , output.append("{} : {}".format(idx,result))

NameError: name 'output' is not defined

Comment: output = [] 
output.append("{} : {}".format(idx,result))  print(output) if i do it like this it will output the last row with the values